# Depth of a generic tree - Python

Tags: python, tree, tree-traversal

I know how to recursively calculate the depth of a binary tree, however I'm not sure I know the best way to calculate the depth of a generic tree where any node n could have k children. I think I've implemented a correct solution below, but I'm wondering if it can be optimized in any way?

```
def depth_binary(node):
    if node == None:
        return 0
    return max(depth(node.left),depth(node.right)) + 1

def depth_tree(node):
    if node == None:
        return 0
    max_val = 0
    for n in node.adjacent:
        d = depth_tree(n)
        if d > max_val:
            max_val = d
    return max_val + 1
```

Comment: In `depth_tree`, you want to return `max + 1`, not `d + 1`.  Also, I recommend using a name other than `max`, since that will mask the `max` function.

Comment: @TomKarzes Ah yes, two bad oversights. Thanks.

Comment: You could replace the loop with `return max([depth_tree(n) for n in node.adjacent]) + 1` if you wanted to.

Comment: @TomKarzes Ah yeah didn't think about using list comprehension. Seems more Pythonic. Is it faster?

Comment: There's really nothing you can do to optimize this in any significant way. You have to visit every node in the tree, so the best you can hope for is O(n), where n is the number of nodes in the tree. Your algorithm achieves an O(n) solution, so it is optimal.

Comment: @Apollo I would expect the performance to be comparable.  Both versions are doing essentially the same work.  One is just a little more compact than the other, but uses an intermediate result list.